# How to create a simple web application just to test my web service using Java

Tags: java, web-services, spring-mvc, struts

I have web service url that I need to test its functionality using Java Web Client.
I've read some in google concerning simple web application using struts framework.
Anybody has simple web application that can consume a web service?

Updates1:
Sorry i am looking for simple web app to start with. Html and servlet because i have to simulate or to create a prototype to demonstrate to my professor our thesis. Basically i need the html for inputs then a submit button then invoke the servlet to consume the ws. Sorry for misleading. Thanks.

Updates2:
I found spring framework to create the view and controller then define the ws in the xml config then from that could be possible to consume it easy. Anybody has a netbeans or eclipse project?

Comment: Why don't you use SoapUI (http://www.soapui.org/) to test your webservice?

Answer (score 1):

Two options (one faster than the other):

1) Use soapUI to test the web service. Simple and clean.

2) If you NEED to build a java ws, then use the ecilpse wizard to develop it from the wsdl and create a main() procedure calling the method in the stub, sending an instance of the input variable (yes, a lot longer!)

Answer (score 0):

If SoapUI doesn't fit you well, read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnayn.html).
You can use [wsimport](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsimport.html) utility to get neccesary WS stubs.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse Java EE edition has a web service explorer which is great if you have a WSDL.

Answer (score 0):

use the axis client for call the web service with minimum line of code.

```
Service service = new Service();
Call call = (Call) service.createCall();
String endpoint ="URL of the WSDL";
call.setTargetEndpointAddress(new URL(endpoint));
call.setOperationName(new QName("webservice method name"));
//input parameter type 
call.addParameter("op1", XMLType.XSD_STRING, ParameterMode.IN);
//output parameter type
call.setReturnType(XMLType.XSD_STRING);
//call web service and return string 
call.invoke(new Object[] { new String("parameter")});
```